# Does changing the value of x change the number of solutions?

Tags: number-theory

So I have the equation:
$$-C<2n+x<C$$

Where
$$n ∈ Z$$
$$C ∈ R$$
$$-1<x<1$$

My question is, for a given value of C, do the same number of values for n always exist, regardless of the value of x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If C = .8, and $x = 0$ then there is one solution, namely $0$.  If $x = -.9$ then the interval in question is $.1 < 2n < 1.7$ which has no solutions.

Comment: Am I right that the number of solutions can only vary by 1?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are.  I'd write it out just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to is how much integers does the interval $\left(\frac{-c-x}{2} , \frac{c - x}{2} \right)$ has for a given $c$ and $-1<x<1$. This interval always contains $0$ unless $|x| \geq |c|$

Comment: Doesnt this only work assuming C is an integer?

Comment: No. If $ c < x$. Look into $-c < 2n + x < c$. Hence $-c -x < 2n < c-x$. Then divide by $2$ we get $\frac{-c-x}{2} < n < \frac{c-x}{2}$. it is given that $x<1$ so $-c -x > -2$ and $c - x < 0 $. Hence $-1 < n < 0$ no integer satisfying this. Note that $c$ is positive since $-c<2n+x<c$ , i.e., $-c<c$.

Comment: In the other hand if $c>x$ then $-c -x <0 $ and $c -x>0$. Hence $-c -x <2n < c-x$ and $n = 0$ is a solution.

Comment: But why are you assuming -c-x>-2 and c-x<0? If you make c=2 neither of those are correct, regardless of x

Comment: I'm pretty confident that it does vary

Comment: Look $x$  is between $-1 <x < 1$. If $c < x$ so it will be $0 < c < 1 $ since it is positive hence $0 > -c > -1 $ but  $x$ satisfy $c<x < 1 $. $-x > -1$, $-c-x > -1 -1 = -2 $

Comment: But c isn't necessarily less than x

Comment: I discuss both cases if $c < x$ then no solution. if $c > x$ we have a solution.